# How do I stop my PHP page from redirecting when it's not supposed to?

Tags: php

My PHP skills are rusty, but I'm trying to build a CRUD site for a project. I had a perfectly good, working edit.php page. If the update query was successful, the user would be redirected to view.php to see the results. Then I added user id validation to make sure users couldn't modify the URL with a random record ID and edit a record belonging to someone else and the page broke. Here's my code:

```
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Other misc stuff

// Get record id from URL
$qdetailsid = $_GET['qdetailsid']; 

// First, check to make sure user owns record to be updated
$sessionid = $_SESSION["id"];

$query = "SELECT userid FROM database WHERE qdetailsid = '$qdetailsid'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$userid = $row['userid'];

if ($userid != $sessionid) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location = '/error'; // IDs don't match, so redirect to error page
    </script>

<?php
    exit; // I've added and removed this; makes no difference.
 } else {

    // IDs match, so process the form
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       // Perform update and redirect to view.php
    } 
} // End of id check           

// Display the edit form pre-populated with data
$query = "SELECT title, url, details FROM database WHERE qdetailsid = '$qdetailsid'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

// Display post content in form
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   // Get form data
   $title = $row['title'];
   $url = $row['url'];
   $details = $row['details'];
} 
// Close connection
$mysqli->close();

// Display the form html
```

If the id's don't match, the page redirects to the error.php page properly. But if they DO match, the code proceeds to process the form submit like it's supposed to. However, even if I submit a valid update, the update fails and the page is redirected to the error page, like it's going back to the id check after attempting to update and finding a mismatch. There is no other redirect to the error page, so that's how it looks to me. If I completely remove the user id check if-else code block, the page works as intended.

It's interesting to note that I can briefly see the edit.php URL in the address bar before the redirect happens. There are no parameters attached, just 'edit.php?'. If I manually try to navigate to edit.php with no parameters, it redirects me to the error page. There is no code set up to do that. I implemented clean URLs via .htaccess, but there is nothing there that handles any error redirection either.

I have the exact same code block in delete.php (if id's don't match, don't delete and send to error page) and it works. I've tried both '!=' and '!==' in the if-else condition.

I've checked throughout SO and can't find a relevant solution for this unique situation.

Note: I'm using javascript to perform the redirects because of php header limitations.

EDIT:
Here's my form code. I didn't include it because I didn't think it was relevant. I didn't change it after adding the userid check code block. Please try not to get hung up on variable names. I edited them to maintain privacy. But they all match properly and, as I said, the form works without the userid check.

```
// IDs match, so process the form
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   // Get form data
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $url = $_POST['url'];
   $details = $_POST['details'];
   $qdetailsid = $_POST['detailsid'];

   // Prepare an update statement
   $update = "UPDATE database SET title = ?, url = ?, qdetails = ? WHERE qdetailsid = ?";

   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($update);

   $stmt->bind_param('sssd', $title, $url, $details, $qdetailsid);

   if($stmt->execute())  {

   // Redirect to view page to see results of update
?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location = '/view/' + <?php echo $qdetailsid ?>; 
      </script>

<?php
      exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use JavaScript or Meta Tags to redirect a web page. Use [`Location: header`](//stackoverflow.com/q/768431/) instead. Check [PHP the Right Way](//phptherightway.com/) for more up-to-date advice.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Use prepared statements! This code is vulnerable to attacks. Don't validate a user's identity with a sessionid... you're asking for trouble!

Comment: The action of your form tag (not shown) needs to be `edit.php?qdetailsid=something` for this to work.  If you don't have that qdetailsid parameter there, I would expect it to kick you to the error page when you submit the form.

Comment: PHP Header limitations? You cannot header redirect if you've echo'ed output to the screen, otherwise there should be nothing standing in your way.

Comment: Yeah, he's using GET and POST together... if the form is submitted via POST, there will be no GET data.

Comment: Everyone, I'm using prepared statements. I'm very familiar with SQL injection, but it wasn't the issue I was presenting, so I didn't include that portion of my code. Also, the action in my form is PHP self. The GET does actually work. It worked just fine before the new code block and does now. I know because I echo'd out the variable to be sure. @Gary, I cannot header redirect if I've echo'ed output to the screen. That is what's standing in my way.

Comment: Can someone please explain why my question was voted down with no explanation? I clearly stated I've checked throughout SO and can't find a relevant solution for this unique situation. What is more thoughtful research? What was unclear or not useful? My profile indicates I'm a new member. I thought this was a helpful forum. I would hope that anyone who believed my question unworthy would take a moment to explain why so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: @GaryHayes, you wrote, "Don't validate a user's identity with a sessionid... you're asking for trouble!" Can you explain that, please? When a user logs in, I set the session id. I am comparing the session id to the user id of the record pulled from my database.

Comment: A wily hacker could intercept the session id and use it to log in as the user, never needing to know the user's password. While they may be able to intercept the password as well ( I always encrypt before sending ), it is a one time transmission, whereas the session id lives as long as the session, giving the hacker plenty of opportunities to obtain it. https may help, but not everyone is using it yet.

Comment: Do all of your processing first, check to see if a redirect needs to be done. If not, then start echo'ing to the page ( load the page they are meant to be on ).

If you're just echo'ing errors for development, try using a file handler and dump to text file, or just turn on error reporting in php.ini

Comment: @GaryHayes, I hash the password before sending. I'm also using https. I've set it up so users get an error redirect if they attempt to change the URL parameter. This is totally off my original topic, but since you opened the door...How else would you suggest I validate userid against what's in my database if session id is unsafe? One thought that comes to mind is having the user re-enter their password, but that's cumbersome. If I post here and want to edit it, I just click the edit link. I want to keep it simple.

Comment: You could add a cookie element to it, and validate the machine, so even if the session id is intercepted, it is useless without also having the cookie. But, since you want to keep it simple, and you're using ssl and encryption, it will probably be fine for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Hey, that's actually a great idea worth looking into. One can never have too much security. Well, one can, but as long as it's not annoying to the user, I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it's going to `error.php` because there's some error in your code (if I remember right, PHP redirects to /error if there's an error unless you have it set differently in the config file).

If the two files `update.php` and `delete.php` are structured identically, but one fails while the other does not, then the failure lies in the difference between the code. In this case, I'd suspect it's in the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` block of code. Can you share that with us?

EDIT: Also, to those commenting about header limitations, I've been in a similar situation as a developer, where I was contractually obligated to *not* interfere with the codebase of the CMS app I was working on, and had to do what I could from inside the theme files. By the time the app got to my code, it had already sent headers, so I had to do a similar workaround.

Comment: Okay, I added my form code. It was working just fine previously and I made no changes to it, that's why I didn't include it. I think I tried wrapping the entire code in the if-else userid block, too, and that didn't work. And you are correct about the header limitations. It's disappointing to take such great care to bring forth an issue and have people focus on the minutiae. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: No problem! Have had plenty of people get lost in the minutiae here, myself, rather than focus on the problem being presented. Does your `error.php` script give you visibility into the error that brought it there, or are you otherwise able to expose that error in your development environment? I'm not seeing anything wrong in the form code that you posted, so the next step, in my opinion, would be to see what PHP is complaining about and go from there. You could probably put `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the top of your file to expose the error (and temporarily turn off the redirect).

Comment: I think I was trying to do too much in one file (contrary to OOP principles). I was validating userid and record id along with trying to process the form. Maybe it can be done, but I just couldn't figure out a way to do it elegantly. I ended up breaking the file into two: one for the form and another for processing. Once I did that, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, I was completely unaware an error log was being generated each time my site error'd out, so once I discovered it I kept referring to that as I was debugging. I had warnings I didn't even know about because everything was just working.

Comment: "I was contractually obligated to not interfere with the codebase of the CMS" - @Jpec07

That is ridiculous. I would have added my own include at the beginning of the file...

Comment: That is ultimately what I wound up doing, @GaryHayes, until I was able to convince management that such a setup was, as you said, ridiculous, and was given the go-ahead to rebuild the app to actually suit our needs.